# While forever on rows in AngularJs Grid

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS's grid and in a column I call a function to return some html.
When debugging this function I noticed it is called infinitely.
I changed the function to only console.log("test") and "test" is printed like crazy.

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm working in this project of my company.

This is the column definition:

```
    {
        field: "statusId", width: '8%', enableSorting: true, displayName: "", enableHiding: false, enableFiltering: false,
        cellTemplate: "<div class='ui-grid-cell-contents' ng-bind-html='grid.appScope.getIcon(row.entity.statusId)'></div>"
    }
```

And the function:

```
$scope.getIcon = function (statusId) {   
    console.log("getIcon");        
};
```

I don't know what code you guys need to help. Let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems a bug, see: [Multiple grid.appScope calls when used in cellTemplate](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3753)

To overcome this, you can use directives.